# display pdf with python using pdfviewer

Tags: python, pdf, wxpython

I'm trying to display a pdf using pdfviewer lib from wx but I can't find the module.
I already have the wxPython installed is it deprecated ?

I'm following this tutorial :

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.pdfviewer.html#module-lib.pdfviewer

And I'm getting : 
`ImportError: No module named pdfviewer`

Comment: My installation doesn't have it either, it may be depricated

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to write comments, so sorry for asking this question as my answer, but have you seen the comment on the website?

> The viewer uses pyPDF2 or pyPdf, if neither of them are installed an import error exception will be thrown.

Comment: Yes, I did, pypdf is installed, but pyPdf is only used for parsing and manipulating pdf files not rendering them.

Answer (score 0):

The PDFViewer works for me, although it's a bit picky about what PDFs it will load. I wasn't able to get it to work with pyPDF2, but it loaded fine with the old pyPDF. I am running wxPython Phoenix 3.0.1 on Windows 7 with Python 2.7. On Windows, there also an ActiveX version of the PDF viewer that might be a bit better. You'll need to make sure you have comtypes installed though if you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

wx.lib.pdfviewer was added in version 2.9.1.1. [link](http://www.wxpython.org/recentchanges.php)
There is a PPA for wxpython 2.9.4.1 (for ubuntu 12.04), so if you happened to use ubuntu 12.04, you can try the PPA. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-dev/wfuCUplyMUs)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:delmic-soft/odemis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.9
```

Then you can do

```
>>> import wx.lib.pdfviewer
>>>
```

However, not sure if it is fully compatible with 2.8.